# Remove GRUB but keep dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have a dual boot system (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04). I have Grub that has some problems finding where Windows 10 is (it cannot find Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi)

However, I realized that every time I press F8, it seems that the motherboard/PC has its own boot loader. I can then choose both Windows and Linux without any problems.

Therefore, as I don't want to spend time configuring GRUB to choose Windows (find where bootmgfw.efi is), I would like to know if it is possible to remove GRUB without messing up my dual boot. I would like to have an OS that is loaded by default and only change it when I press F8 on boot.

Is that possible to do it? how to remove GRUB safely then?

Comment: You can't remove GRUB.  Even if you were not dual booting, GRUB is still needed. Why don't you ask about the problem you think you have with GRUB?

Comment: Cannot just remove grub, but could replace it with another boot loader(more than I can help).  Adding more info about your setup and the main problem in your question could help someone advise you.  Quite a few google questions about grub not finding windows, with answers.